# Ignore missing files in Git

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

My Git repo contains files ending in a period which will not clone onto a PC.  When I clone the repo onto a PC, these files automatically show up as deleted (and the deletions are automatically staged to be committed).

Is there a way to tell Git to ignore these files' absence and not to delete them from the repo?  I've tried .gitignore, but that is for ignoring files which ARE present in the working directory and are NOT part of the repo, which is kind of exactly the opposite concept of what I'm looking for here.

Obviously I can unstage the deletions, but I don't want to have to do that every time I pull.

Comment: maybe it's not so obvious that I can unstage the deletions - having trouble finding a command line command that will do that since the file was never present in this clone of the repo  (and cannot be).

Comment: obviously the best answer is "don't use file names in your repo that can't exist on the file system you're actually working on" but for the sake or argument, let's assume that's not an option here...

Comment: What filesystem are you using?

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11366713/14660) should do what you want.